# intersection number of a surface and a rational normal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $C$ be a degree $n (\ge 4)$ rational curve  and $X$ be a degree $m ( \ge 2)$ smooth projective surface in  $\mathbb{P}^n$. In general a curve and a surface do not meet provided $n \ge 4$. By Bezout's theorem, if they intersect, then they intersect in at most $mn$ points. Suppose $C \cap X$ is non-empty. Then what would be lower bound of the intersection number ? Is it possible to find a degree $n$ rational curve which intersects $X$ at more than $n+2$ points ?

Comment: I guess you want to exclude the possibility that $C \subset X$.
For a *lower* bound, I'd expect that typically if $C$ intersects $X$
then they intersect in only one point, so the only valid lower bound
would be the trivial $1$; am I missing some reason why they must meet
in a second point?

Comment: Yes.  We are assuming $C$ is not contained in $X$.  Probably you are right. Actually I have presented my question wrongly. By Veronese's theorem given a general set of $n+3$ points there exists a unique degree $n$ rational curve in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Somehow I feel that a smooth surface always contains more than one general points. So my question should be can we always achieve  the maximal intersection number $mn$ ? If not then what would be the maximal intersection number we can achieve ?

Comment: I don't know.  If $m=2$ then I think $X$ must be contained in a hyperplane,
and then there are at most $n$ intersection points.  For $m\geq 3$ 
it's less clear to me.

Comment: A naive count suggests that for $n>15$, for a sufficiently general surface $X$ of large degree, there is a 12-parameter family of rational normal curves that intersect $X$ in a zero-dimensional scheme of length $n+5$ and no rational curves of degree $\leq n$ that intersects $X$ in a zero-dimensional scheme of length $\geq n+6$ points.  You might be asking for a classification of those surfaces that are "not sufficiently general".  You might be asking for the maximal intersection length for non-general surfaces, etc.  What precisely are you asking?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is an arbitrary smooth projective non-degenerated surface in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Then the question is does there exists a rational curve of degree $n$ which intersects $X$ at at least $n+2$ points ?

Comment: It will be very nice if you kindly suggest some references of the statements you made.

Comment: I do not know a reference, but I can give a full proof for surfaces that are complete intersections of sufficiently general ample hypersurfaces of degree $\geq 2$.  I do not know if there are "nonexamples".  My intuition suggests that rational normal surfaces of degree $n-1$ *might* be nonexamples, but I have not "worked it out".

Comment: Could you please give the proof of the nonexistence of degree $n$ rational curve intersecting a surface at more than $n+5$ points ? Somehow I feel that given any degree $d$, nondegenerated surface $X$ there is a degree $n$ rational curve intersecting $X$ in $3(d-n+3)$ points.